# Unix script to search for a specific keyword in all files and sub directories of a directories or folder

Tags: shell, unix, grep, find

I am working on a shell script that will search for a specific keyword in all log files and subfolders in a folder.

I am using below grep command but it is displaying the keyword only from the current directory but not from subdirectories. in my case, I have bunch of subdirectories where the log files will be there where it is not displaying the files from subdirectory.

```
grep -r -H "Keyword" *.log
```

please suggest how can I achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong parameter and the wrong command. With grep, it should be `-R` and you can only search in directories.

```
grep -R -H "Keyword" .
```

But I think you want to use find.

```
find . -name '*.log' -exec grep -H "Keyword" {} \;
```

Comment: Use the `-l` option if you only want the filenames instead of `./path/to/dir/test.log:Keyword`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
find /dir_name/ -type f -name "*.log" -exec grep -l "your_string" {} \+ 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Try the `-name` option like this one stackoverflow.com/questions/57721685/#57721767 :-)